# Intelligence Dataset

Tags: cognitive-psychology, intelligence

I'm looking for a standard and large dataset relating to cognitive performance. Ideally the data would look something like a standard IQ test, but including the raw answers, and designed to test more than just verbal and analytical skills, but other facets of intelligence as well. I'd also settle for a sufficiently large dataset of IQ tests with scores. Does such a dataset that is standard in academic research exist, and if so is it publicly available?